# why does a constructor work this way?

Tags: c#, activemq-classic

I have a constructor in c#, could just as well be Java, for a class that uses activeMQ. The class is instantiated multiple times, each time to publish on a separate topic, as defined by the variable `String destination` passed to the constructor, as follows:

```
class Publisher
{
  // Class variables constructed in constructor then used from outside class
  public IConnection connection = null;
  public ISession session = null;
  public IMessageProducer producer = null;

  // Constructor
  public Publisher (String destination)
  {
    String user = "USER";
    String password = "PASSWORD";
    String host = "localhost";
    int port = Int32.Parse("61616");

    String brokerUri = "activemq:tcp://" + host + ":" + port;
    NMSConnectionFactory factory = new NMSConnectionFactory(brokerUri);

    connection = factory.CreateConnection(user, password);
    connection.Start();
    session = connection.CreateSession(AcknowledgementMode.AutoAcknowledge);
    IDestination dest = session.GetTopic(destination);
    producer = session.CreateProducer(dest);
    producer.DeliveryMode = MsgDeliveryMode.NonPersistent;
  }

  public void Stop ()
  {
    producer.Send(session.CreateTextMessage("SHUTDOWN"));
    connection.Close();
    Console.ReadLine();
  }

  public void Publish(String data)
  {
    producer.Send(session.CreateTextMessage(data));
  }
}
```

The question is how does the compiler know to assign the 3 activeMQ public variables `connection, session, producer` to the relevant instance?

i.e. from other classes I can call

```
Publisher pub1 = new Publisher("topic1");
Publisher pub2 = new Publisher("topic2");
Publisher pub3 = new Publisher("topic3");
```

and then

```
pub1.Publish("stuff1");
pub2.Publish("stuff2");
pub3.Publish("stuff3");
```

and everything is working. The "stuffs" are all published to the correct topics and there's no need to explicitly pass in the 3 public activeMQ variables `connection, session, producer` which are not always the same, the producer and session each instantiated with the different destination...

Anyway, it works but I'd like to understand more about why, and how each constructor knows which instance.

Comment: That's basic OOP.  The [constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_%28object-oriented_programming%29) is executed on an instance when it's created - any instance fields/properties apply only to that instance.  On a side note - your constructor is doing WAY too much work.  Constructors should only do the bare minimum to create a class.  Any further actions should be done via methods (`Init`, `Connect`, `Start`, etc.)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about, those are variables of `Publisher` instances. This isn't really the place to ask how a compiler works.

Comment: @D Stanley, thx, so the only difference across 100 instances is the 1 property "destination" and that's enough for each instance to have unique pointer address when it's instantiated... so it can be found if called, and then everything else is all there in address space?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Each instance has it's own block of memory. Each one has its own `connection` variable, for example.

Comment: @D Stanley, hmm, constructor does too much, so then for each topic i want to publish to then make class instance, then init... hmm an extra line per topic...

Comment: @rupweb "destination" is not a property, it's a parameter to your constructor, which initializes the `connection`, `session`, and `producer` fields, each of which is part of that instance's state.

Comment: @rupweb a light constructor is a [design principle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229060%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  They should do as little as possible to give you a valid instance.  Your constructor does set the instance fields, but also tries to connect to external resources.  That action should be explicitly done in a separate method so the client can _choose_ when to connect.

Comment: @D Stanley, thx. Guess my app has hundreds of instances of 'connection, session' and 'producer' objects all packed away in different memory blocks, each having an address according to 'destination'. Or, is each instance have its own pointer to some master 'connection, session' and 'producer' objects?

Comment: @rupweb Each instance will have it's own `connection`, `session` and `producer` objects.  And they are isolated by _instance_, not by _destination_ - meaning if you create another `Publisher` with the same destination parameter the two object will _not_ share that state.

Comment: And having "hundreds" of objects is probably not a big deal - even if an object is 1MB in size (which is huge for a single object), you're still only at 100MB which isn't much on modern machines.  Don't worry about memory usage until it actually becomes a problem.

Comment: Thx, right, what's desirable is to setup the one connection, in the constructor, because all the sessions, each having discrete destinations and producers, use the same connection. If the connection doesn't complete nothing works. Then put all the session, destination and producer constructions in the Publish method, and build them up and tear them down with every Publish... Hmmm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66685/discussion-between-rupweb-and-d-stanley).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each class instance has its own memory block regardless of `destination` variable.

Following [constructor design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229060%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) I moved the `session`, `destination` and `producer` objects to a method. These all ought to use the one `connection`, probably, now in a `try / catch` block although that probably ought to be a method as well.

Call the new method somewhere, having instantiated the class.